# Can't logout authentication laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, logout

I can't seem to log out from my account in laravel. I have use the chrome development tool and it told me that it was the fault of my app.js file. So I remove it and replace it with the original copy of the app.js file but the error still remain there with the old previous code. I also didn't really touch any of the login and logout function, only the app.blade.php but in the past I was able to still logout from the account. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

The error it return me was this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at app.js:2
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">


                    <title>SideBar Menu</title>
     <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sidebar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="sidebar-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });

    </script>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->

                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (I am using the old file that I had used, sorry can't upload the whole code because max word limit)
[image]

Comment: also post your app.js file code

Comment: @JunaidAhmad thanks for replying but for the app.js it is quite long and I am not sure if I should put it in the question, do you have any suggestion on how to post the app.js? Like maybe attach file or something